# Update namecheap domain records to smartermail server

Tags: domain, email-server, email, namecheap

I have installed a smartermail server on my Windows Azure web instance. I was able to send a test email (and receive it in my yahoo inbox), so I assume that everything on the Azure end is already configured.

Assume that I have all the settings at the defaults, what settings should I update in Namecheap so that the emails direct to my domain will be directed to my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up an [MX Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) on your domain to let the sending server know who is responsible for receiving mail.

Comment: I have 5 rows with 4 inputs in each:
HOST NAME, MAILSERVER HOST NAME, MX PREF and TTL

any suggestion what I should fill in these?
Thanks.

Comment: Host name would be the part after the @ in your mail address. It's most likely your domain name.. The Mailserver host name is the name of the server that is processing the mail. You can set up an A- or a CNAME-Record like mail.example.com. The Pref is important if you have multiple mailservers for one domain. If you only have a single server you can set it to whatever you want. I'd suggest 10. The TTL is the time your record will stay in a cache if it is once fetched from the DNS server. 3600 (two hours) is a good value.